# H2-Database console not opening with Spring-Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, h2

I'm using the `H2-Database` and `Spring Security`, but I'm unable to open it in the browser at `http://localhost:8080/h2-console`

Here my `pom.xml` (only the `H2` entry)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/noNameDB
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

And here is my `SecurityConfig.java`

```
import com.example.noName.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.example.noName.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITE_LIST = {
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/v2/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/h2-console/**",
            "/console/**",
            "/account/**"
    };

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITE_LIST)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

The following is shown in the console if I try to access the console via `http://localhost:8080/h2-console`

```
INFO 3664 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 3664 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
INFO 3664 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

---

I have already tried everything I could find on the Internet.

The funny thing is that the "exception handling" works for `Swagger`.
If I try to access the database via:

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console
```

I always get the error:

```
401 - Unauthorized
```

Each one is strange, because the access was allowed in the `SecurityConfig`.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITE_LIST)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}
```

I can access the database through an internal database test. This is provided by `Intellij`.

However `working`/`editing` in the database is not possible through this.

AND:

If I change the `AUTH_WHITE_LIST` to this, it works.

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITE_LIST = {
       "/**"
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Marc! Could you attach also `JWTAuthorizationFilter` with your specific code configurations inside, please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I could reproduce with [spring-boot:3.0.0(web, security, h2, ...)](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=19&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,security,h2,data-jpa) and:

```
return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/h2-console/**")
        .and()
        .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .and()
        .build();
```

(`/h2-console` is still protected!)

#### Fix:

(spring-boot-way):

```
import static //
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest.toH2Console; // !
...
  .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()
  ...
  .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console())
```

Refs:

- https://jessitron.com/2020/06/15/spring-security-for-h2-console/
- [`PathRequest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/PathRequest.java)

It uses internally:

> ```
> new AntPathRequestMatcher(h2ConsoleProperties.get().getPath() + "/**");
> ```

which seems to be different/better than the `requestMatcher(String... paths)` ([`AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java)), which invokes this (with `method==null`):

> ```
> public C requestMatchers(HttpMethod method, String... patterns) {
>    List<RequestMatcher> matchers = new ArrayList<>();
>    if (mvcPresent) {
>       matchers.addAll(createMvcMatchers(method, patterns)); // <- we land here obviously
>    } else {
>       matchers.addAll(RequestMatchers.antMatchers(method, patterns));     
>    }
>   return requestMatchers(matchers.toArray(new RequestMatcher[0]));
> }
> ```

... alternatives:

- `RequestMatchers.antMatcher(null, pathToH2+"/**")`.
- [`AntPathRequestMatcher`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.java) (for ignore case (*and all* http methods), prefer constructors to factories;)
- <del>`MvcMatcher`</del> (is not possible for h2-console, since it is not mvc;(

#### BUT/AND

I would ***not do it (unsecured) in production***!

Comment: Life saviour! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 7):

In Spring boot 3, you need to add the following configurations:

first

```
.csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console())
            .disable())
```

second

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
        .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll())
```

third

```
.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the post on spring blog about [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) we can use WebSecurityCustomize for ignoring the whole endpoint from the security.
The case fits perfectly to publish the h2 console, because we want to ignore only this particular endpoint in the case of security.
The working example:

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher(H2_CONSOLE_PATH));
}
```

And that's all what we need, probably the cleanest solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can also explicitly fallback to antMatcher inside `requestMatchers`:

```java
import static org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher;
....

.....
return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
              .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .build();
```

Comment: Could you please provide the complete SecurityFilterChain? This code snippet doesn't work at all - at least not with Spring Security 6.

Comment: This is the only One that worked fr me <3

Comment: @silentsudo, if that worked, do you mind upvoting the solution so it's going to get bumped up and others are going to notice it as well?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to create a new AntPathRequestMatcher within:

```
.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
```

To avoid problems of display the frames (X-Frame-Options header will be not added by Spring Security in the response):

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the snippet of my code. I use Spring Boot 3.0.6. It works.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                .and().csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**"))
                .and().headers().frameOptions().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Do import in your SecurityConfig class

```
import static org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest.toH2Console;
```

Step 2: Add filter in to context. Pay attention to the lines containing the comment '<-'

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                // another matchers
                .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll() // <-
                // another matchers
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((login) -> login
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout
                .permitAll()
            )
            .csrf((protection) -> protection
                .ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console()) // <- 
            )
            .headers((header) -> header
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this article, where the question is well explained:
[h2-database-console-with-spring-security](https://springframework.guru/using-the-h2-database-console-in-spring-boot-with-spring-security/)

Note: The article is not updated to Spring Security 6, due the known deprecation of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.
The code should be updated to:

```
package com.myapp.configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import static org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest.toH2Console;  
@Configuration
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration{
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()
        .and().csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console())
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().httpBasic();
        
        // Use them only in development or demo environments. NEVER in production !!!
        // http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```